# How can I login to a program in Linux with a .sh script?

Tags: bash, shell, prompt

I'm sure that this is somewhere on stack overflow, but I've been researching this for hours and none of the answers work.

I need to answer prompts in a .sh script to log in to different accounts automatically.

My script will not answer the prompts automatically.

```
#!/bin/bash

program9000 login
```

That part works fine.

Then i get a series of prompts and cannot figure out how to get the .sh script to reply automatically.  I will be replying to these 4 prompts the same way every time.

**Would you like to enter a new key?**

I would like to reply 
`y`

**How would you like to authenticate?**
**1. enter password**
**2. do something else**
**3. do something else**
**q. Quit**

I would like to reply 
`1`

**Enter your password, please**

I would like to reply 
`mypassword`

**Enter your Domain name, please**

I would like to reply 
`https://mydomain.mine.com`

Please note that I am not writing the prompts, they are coming from program9000.  I just want to reply with the same 4 responses every time.

The following have not worked in my .sh script
`yes`
`echo`
`send`

What should the following lines of my script look like?

Here are some things that don't work

```
#!/bin/bash

program9000 login
send "y" 
send "1"
send "fakepassword"
send "https://fakedomain.com"
```

```
#!/bin/bash

program9000 login
{ send -- "y" }
{ send -- "1" }
{ send -- "fakepassword"
{ send -- "https://fakedomain.com" }
```

Comment: Maybe try the `expect` utility, you can search in this forum.

Comment: "The following have not worked in my .sh script `yes` `echo` `send`" Please post the exact scripts you tried, and the exact results of trying them.

Comment: Something like `printf '1\nmypassword\nhttps://mydomain.mine.com' |  ./script.sh`?

Comment: it doesn't respond to the first prompt.  the prompt waits to hear from me, then the script fails.  How would you all do it?

Comment: @ErikG: have you tried my suggestion?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk yes, it doesn't reply to the first prompt.  once I manually reply to that prompt, i get the next prompt.  when i'm done manually putting in prompts, the strings just print on a new line.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use expect language, available almost with every *nix distributive
2. You can send multiline "answerfile" or string to your program using redirection

```
program9000 login <<< "
y
1
fakepassword
https://fakedomain.com"
```

Comment: This was the first solution to produce a different result.  I saw the first prompt, then a new bash line came up where my response would go.

Answer (score 0):

As others have already mentioned, use `expect`.

> ```
> apt show expect
> ...
> Description: Automates interactive applications
>  Expect is a tool for automating interactive applications according to a script.
>  Following the script, Expect knows what can be expected from a program and what
>  the correct response should be.
>  ...
> ```

See the [expect man page here](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect)

To install it on Debian or it's derivatives:

```
apt install expect
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use expect.
My English is terrible.So I write a example.

fakeprogram9000.sh

```
assert_var()
{
        if [ $1 != $2 ]; then
                echo err; exit 1
        fi
}


read -p 'Would you like to enter a new key?' var1
assert_var $var1 'y'

read -p 'How would you like to authenticate?' var1
assert_var $var1 '1'

read -p 'Enter your password, please' var1
assert_var $var1 'fakepassword'

read -p 'Enter your Domain name, please' var1
assert_var $var1 'https://fakedomain.com'
echo success
```

example.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

expect<<EOF
spawn bash ./fakeprogram9000.sh login
expect "Would you like to enter a new key?" {send "y\r"}
expect "How would you like to authenticate?" {send "1\r"}
expect "Enter your password, please" {send "fakepassword\r"}
expect "Enter your Domain name, please" {send "https://fakedomain.com\r"}
expect eof
EOF
```